# dynamically change column in excel sumifs

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have created a dynamic table in excel through a SUMIFS formula:

```
=SUMIFS(data!$D:$D,data!$B:$B,Sheet2!B$3,data!$C:$C,Sheet2!B$2,data!$A:$A,Sheet2!$A4)
```

this is what the table looks like:

[image]

while the data looks like:

[image]

Now I am picking values from the column Order Total. What I would like to do is to insert a dropdown list on cell B1 to dynamically select from what column I want to get the data.

Is there a way to add this in my formula?

Comment: What you want to use is an "indirect" formula, but I am a little confused as to where to put it. Does your sumifs formula need a different column for data? Just one of the sumifs or all of them? If you tell me where you want it I can help with the indirect.

To create a dropdown in cell B1 to reference, use data validation (menu ribbon -> data -> data validation -> select 'list' and fill in the values you want ('A','B','C').

Comment: If you look at the first image I uploaded the cells are the result of the sumifs formula. What I want is to replace that formula with a new one that will change the data column based on a value that i will put in B1 that is either Order_total or Count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since order total is in column D, I'll replace the first piece of the sumifs with the indirect, and I'm assuming the data is on the data worksheet, as well as cell B1 which you want the dropdown: `=SUMIFS(indirect("data!$"&data!B1&":$"&data!B1),data!$B:$B,Sheet2!B$3,data!$C:$C,Sheet2!B$2,data!$A:$A,Sheet2!$A4)`

What the indirect does is concatenate (using the '&' symbol) the string information with the cell information, then change it to a cell reference. If you copy everything within the indirect into another cell (preceded by "="), it would return your original `data!$D:$D`, if you put "D" in cell B1. This then becomes the cell references for the sumifs formula when using the indirect formula. If you change cell B1 on the Data worksheet to "E", the formula would evaluate to `data!$E:$E` within the indirect, which would then mean the sumifs formula references column E.