# SUMIFS with column selection in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, aggregate, vlookup, sumifs

Suppose I have a table like this:

| Branch | Type | Jan | Feb | Mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b1 | Other | 100 | 120 | 130 |
| b1 | Other | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| b1 | Rent | 5 | 6 | 6 |
| b2 | Lease | 2 | 2 | 5 |
| b2 | Rent | 1 |  | 1 |
| b2 | Other | 2 |  | 4 |

I want to aggregate data and get a new table for the branch b1:

|  | Jan | Feb | March |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Other | 110 | 140 | 160 |
| Rent | 5 | 6 | 6 |
| Lease | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I have tried to run sumifs, but it doesn't just work because I want to choose the appropriate column based on month values. Non-matching ranges obviously give the `#VALUE` error.

I have tried to select the right columns within `sumifs` from the source table using `index`, `match` but I get `#N/A`

When I just select the right column in the source manually, `sumifs` returns zeros even though the source table has numbers.

Can I sum cells from the source based on multiple conditions across rows and columns? Preferably without macros involved.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330730/dynamically-change-column-in-excel-sumifs) seems to be solving a similar issue but I do not understand what the formula does and how to apply it in my case.

Comment: I would try sumproduct() with index() and match()

Comment: Please share the formulas you have tried.

Comment: SUMIFS should work fine with INDEX/MATCH. From your example the columns are in the same order so there's no need for it, but I presume that is a simplified version of what you are really doing?

Comment: @Rory there is just one more column betweem branch and type. other than that the table is quite representative of my original data.

Comment: Then you'd simply lock the criteria ranges of the formula and only lock the rows for the sum range, then copy across.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this like this:

[image]

Formula in cell H4 is:

```
=SUMIFS(CHOOSE(MATCH(H$3;$C$1:$E$1;0);$C$2:$C$7;$D$2:$D$7;$E$2:$E$7);$A$2:$A$7;"b1";$B$2:$B$7;$G4)
```

For this formula to work the month names must be **exactly** the same in both headers (Notice in your example you use `March` and `Mar`).

Also, notice I'm using `"b1"` raw value to filter Branch but you can link this to a cell and calculate for b1, b2 and so on.

Anyways, Just a suggestion, consider using [Pivot Tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) to get all data ypu want with a few clicks:

[image]

Comment: Your implementation of SUMIFS works great! Today I learnt how to use the CHOOSE function. Marked as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Or use `INDEX($C$2:$E$7;0;MATCH(H$3;$C$1:$E$1;0))` instead of the CHOOSE

Answer (score 3):

Assuming no **`Excel Constraints`** as per the tags posted, then you could try the following formula, which will spill the required output for **`Branch`** --> `B1`. Also the reason for posting a dynamic spill array as per the OP

> *I want to aggregate data and get a new table for the branch b1:*

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, FILTER(B2:E7,A2:A7="b1"),
     b, TAKE(a,,1),
     c, DROP(a,,1),
     ub, UNIQUE(b),
     REDUCE(B1:E1,ub,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,HSTACK(y,BYCOL(c,LAMBDA(z,SUM(--(y=b)*z))))))))
```

---

Or, use a cell reference to change the **`Branch`**

[image]

---

Answer (score 2):

### Sum If Monthly

```
=LET(table,A1:F11,uVal,H2,
    dt,DROP(table,,1),
    d,FILTER(DROP(dt,1),DROP(TAKE(table,,1),1)=uVal),
    uc,TAKE(d,,1),
    u,UNIQUE(uc),
    ud,DROP(d,,1),
    dr,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(u),COLUMNS(ud),LAMBDA(r,c,
        SUM(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(ud,c),uc=CHOOSEROWS(u,r))))),
VSTACK(TAKE(dt,1),HSTACK(u,dr)))
```

[image]